# Is there a faster way to parse and edit values in a row based on values in other rows that I have to search for?

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

I'm trying to parse through a long dataframe in R. I am looking for rows with values in the tau column that have a value greater than 0.7. I then am finding all the other rows in the long format dataframe that have the same designation in the geneID column and same designation in the species column, but different designations in the tissue columns. I have to check which of these have the highest value in log2expression, and then place the designation of that tissue in the biased column for each of those rows with the same geneID and species columns. I have a working for loop for it, but its slow and rather ugly at the moment:

```
long_tau$biased <- 'general'
for(gRow in 1:nrow(long_tau)) {
  print(gRow)
  if(!is.nan(long_tau$tau[gRow])){
      if(long_tau$tau[gRow] >= 0.7){
        tmpGenes <- long_tau %>% filter_all(any_vars(. %in% c(long_tau$GeneID[gRow]))) %>%
        filter_all(any_vars(. %in% c(long_tau$species[gRow]))) 
        long_tau$biased[gRow] <- tmpGenes[which.max(tmpGenes$log2Expression),]$tissue
  }}
}
```

I was wondering what I could do to make it more efficient. I was thinking I could try designating the biased column all at once for all those filtered rows that I put in the tmpGenes dataframe. Then I could skip all rows that have a different string than 'general' in the biased column.I don't know how I would do that though. Other ideas for making this more efficient are welcome.

The data looks like this:

| GeneID | tau | species | tissue | log2Expression | biased |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Solyc01g005000.3 | 0.7000207 | lyc | styungerm | 5.40986856 | styungerm |

Each time I make tmpGenes it has three rows, one for each tissue.

Thanks for any help.
Added in some rows here using dput() as requested.

```
structure(list(GeneID = c("Solyc01g005000.3", "Solyc01g005010.4", 
"Solyc01g005020.3", "Solyc01g005030.4", "Solyc01g005040.3", "Solyc01g005050.4", 
"Solyc01g005060.3"), tau = c(0.700020714228337, 0.519089831890165, 
0.527472673446906, 0.513496977771781, NaN, 1, 1), species = c("lyc", 
"lyc", "lyc", "lyc", "lyc", "lyc", "lyc"), tissue = c("styungerm", 
"styungerm", "styungerm", "styungerm", "styungerm", "styungerm", 
"styungerm"), log2Expression = c(5.40986855973033, 3.79990010472802, 
5.94750789262394, 5.27701171052278, 0, 0, 0), specific = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), PME = c(FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), PMEI = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), biased = c("styungerm", "general", 
"general", "general", "general", "pollen", "leaf")), row.names = 6:12, class = "data.frame")
```

Rows in tmpGenes:

```
structure(list(GeneID = c("Solyc07g005715.1", "Solyc07g005715.1", 
"Solyc07g005715.1"), tau = c(1, 1, 1), species = c("lyc", "lyc", 
"lyc"), tissue = c("styungerm", "pollen", "leaf"), log2Expression = c(0, 
0.574076953583166, 0), specific = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), PME = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE), PMEI = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), biased = c("general", 
"general", "general")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Yeah, this can certainly be sped up with a grouped operation. It seems hard to illustrate on a single row of data... could you share maybe 5 rows as well as the corresponding output? `dput()` is nicest for sharing as it will be copy/pasteable, e.g.,` dput(long_tau[1:5, ])` for the first 5 rows (pick a suitable subset to illustrate the problem).

Comment: Hi Gregor Thomas. I added in some rows using dput but I'm not sure they're formatted in a way that would be useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base` R, consider `ave` to calculate aggregates by one or more groups. Note below uses the lambda like symbol, `\(x)` introduced in R 4.1.0. Use `function(x)` for prior versions.

```r
long_tau <- within(
  long_tau, {
    # CALCULATE MAX log2Expression BY GeneID AND species
    max_log2exp <- ave(log2Expression, GeneID, species, FUN=\(x) max(x, na.rm=TRUE)) 

    # CONDITIONALLY ASSIGN NEW biased COLUMN
    biased <- ifelse(
        log2Expression == max_log2exp & tau >= 0.7 & !is.na(tau), tissue, "general"
    )

    # REMOVE HELPER CALCULATION
    rm(max_log2exp)
  }
)
```

Comment: Hi Parfait. It almost works. It doesn't seem to work when there's an NaN value for Tau. It also seemed to have some issues for some places where Tau was 1, classifying them as general when they should be biased towards some tissue. I'll try editing it from what you've done though because it was ridiculously fast.

Comment: I think the issue is that it is not correctly editing the biased column for other rows, and for some reason is having issues skipping over NaN and <0.7 Tau values.

Comment: My apologies. I overlooked the `tau >= 0.7` and NaN condition, easily fixed by adding it to the `ifelse` logic.

Comment: Hey that works. It didn't do what I was originally hoping for, placing the tissue that the gene was biased in as its designation for the other two occurrences of that gene in that species, but this may actually work better for my data. Thanks.